# Payload is too large - sending to the server an array larger than 1mb of base64 images

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, strapi

Basically I'm trying to send an array of base64 images. Upon checking its size, it seems that if the length of the array is above 1 million bytes, I get an error when trying to upload the array: payload is too large.

My system specs:
-Local enviourment
-Reactjs
-Mlab as the database
-Strapi as headless CMS
-Graphql plugin for the query

The graphql query (not sure if it matters):

The obj is the object with the array with the base64 images.

I'm not sure where I should try to change the settings: on strapi or mlab? my enviourment is local so it's not related to a host.

Thanks in advance

```
const response = await strapi.request('POST', '/graphql', {
        data: {
          query: `mutation UpdateExam($input: updateExamInput!) {
            updateExam(input: $input) {
              exam { 
                questions 
              }
            }
          }`,
          variables: {
            input: {
              where: {
                id: this.props.match.params.id
              },
              data: {
                questions: obj
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

EDIT:

I've contacted strapi support team and still haven't - and probably won't since it's been a few days already - receive an answer.
I'm suspecting it's one of the node modules who limit the json object size, and not strapi.

Plus - after some research I've discovered that generally speaking it's not a good idea to send to the server a very large json object since it's time consuming. So it turns out that a 1mb json object is actually pretty large.

I would still love to hear more experienced programmers' opinions.
Thank you

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946898/strapi-graphql-413-payload-too-large-request-error?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C123.9578) can help you. I think that we had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used strapi but I guess there must be a setting for the maximum allowed filesize in the strapi config.

Comment: Yap if you go in your admin panel, then in the Plugin link in the menu, you will see a cog for Upload plugin.
In this page you will be able to update the max size you allow.

If it's not enough, check your server configuration (it can come from here)

Comment: It's not working guys. The settings in the File Upload plugin are set to 50mb, but as I said - I'm NOT UPLOADING A FILE, i'm sending a JSON object, so I guess the upload file plugin isn't even being used.

I haven't found any general settings on Starpi related to maximum filesize upload.

Comment: Oh and what server do you mean? I'm developing locally, do you think it could be realted to mlab? I couldn't find any settings there to be changed

Answer (score 0):

In the STRAPI 3.5+ you need to go `config/middleware.js`

and set the size by choosing form limit and jsonLimit

```
 module.exports = {
   settings: {
+    parser:{
+      enabled: true,
+      multipart: true,
+      jsonLimit: "10mb",
+      formLimit: "10mb",
+    },
```