# Strapi GraphQL 413 Payload too large request error

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, strapi, koa, body-parser

I have this issue only in graphql. I need to POST base64 html but I didn't find any configuration for graphql to override the 1mb limitation.
I already setup the middleware.js and choose upper value but it works only for REST API

Answer (score 0):

Inside this github [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11558) can solve it. Temporary but it works.

Change the `config/plugins.js`

```
module.exports = {
   graphql: {
      endpoint: "/customendpoint"
   }
};
```

In fact, the endpoint `/graphql` don't pass by the parser middleware so the request doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I resolved **payload is too large** issue on strapi graphql , in REST apis after I configure json limit and formlimit its working but not in graphql strapi in new version. so I find out the solution. and its working great.

config/plugins.js

```
module.exports = {
  graphql: {
    config: {
      endpoint: "/graphql",
      shadowCRUD: true,
      playgroundAlways: false,
      depthLimit: 7,
      amountLimit: 2000,
      apolloServer: {
        tracing: false,
        bodyParserConfig: {
          // koa-bodyparser/node_modules/co-body/lib/json.js#36
          limit: "256mb",
          // koa-bodyparser/index.js#69
          formLimit: "256mb",
          jsonLimit: "256mb",
          textLimit: "256mb",
          xmlLimit: "256mb",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```